# Android: Why if I create a bitmap that will overwrite the previous during a process the occupied ram increases? How can I avoid it?

Tags: android, service, process, bitmap, ram

I have a big problem.

I create a service that update a bitmap programmatically. When a new bitmap is created the previous previous stays in the RAM memory, so after after some time this process occupies a lot of RAM.

How I can maintain the same occupied RAM?

Many thanks

Comment: .recycle() the bitmap and set it to null before overwriting it.

Comment: Many thanks Simon, can you give me an example code? Thanks again!

Comment: I've edited NikkyDs' answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
if (mBitmap != null){
    mBitmap.recycle();
    mBitmap = null;
}

mBitmap = newBitmap;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but I get NullPointerException when I try to do this..

Comment: if there is a bitmap assigned to mBitmap, then there will be no NullPointerEx.

Comment: Can you give me a valid example?

Comment: of what ? the above is all you need to get rid of the old bitmap